# what is the use of Content-Length in php header?

Tags: php

I have use the below code for downloading file

```
$full_path_file=ctrl_options::GetSystemOption('sentora_root') . "etc/tmp/". basename($backup);

$file_for_user=basename($backup);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");    
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_for_user.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_path_file));
readfile($full_path_file);
```

It will be download the file with faullt because i won't unzipped a file.
I will comment the below line

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_path_file));
```

it's working fine. Let me know the clearcut functionality of the  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_path_file));?

Comment: its not a "php header" its a "http header"

Comment: Ok. Thank you @jmattheis . Let me know the use of http header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($full_path_file)); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think,
before downloading any file, browser should know what size of file you are downloading. And browser/download manager can manage download, part of downloaded data etc